# Find custom distribution parameters that best fit the PDF/CDF data histograms

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, histograms

I have the probability and cummulative density histograms of some data. I need to find the parameters of a custom distribution that best fit the data. For probability distributions included in mathematica, one could use the FindDistribution or the FindDistributionParameters functionalities. Is there any similar function i could use in my case?

Comment: Have you checked `NonlinearModelFit`?